# Send email to the address in one column with body from another, when a keyword is present

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I need to send mail notification to specific email address in Column A2 with body email from B2 when writing keyword in C2. Column A will be filled up from a Google Form.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15HrfUNhIyqLD948aRq0h9iAUW4Y_9LGe8HQm3MP2rZ0/edit?usp=sharing

```
function kirim() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 1;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "test meneh from spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: email trigger script? Assuming you have it written in JS hence the tag, what does the current code look like?

Comment: I can see you are new to StackOverflow, it is a good practice to list the various ways you have tried to solve the problem.  I recommend posting your code in your question so that when you take down your test page other users can see the work too.

Comment: Yes im new, i have put the code above

Answer (score 1):

I dont't really know what the trigger column is for and there was any subject so I left it blank.  But this should do what you need.  You'll probably need to change the sheetname and if you want to call this with a timer based trigger you may want to replace the first line with `var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetID');`

```
function kirim()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('SimpleEmail');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var changed=false;
  var re=/ok/i;
  for(var i=1;i<rngA.length;i++)
  {
    if(rngA[i][2].match(re))//case insensitive and of the following will work: Ok ok oK OK 
    {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(rngA[i][0], '', rngA[i][1]);
      rngA[i][3]='EMAIL_SENT';
      changed=true;
    }
  }
  if(changed)rng.setValues(rngA);     
}
```

Comment: i mean,  when i write "ok" in C2 it will automatically send email to specific email address in Col A2 with body email from B2

Comment: Okay, It's set up for that now.